# Jetty 9.2.2 JDK 1.7 Cargo Daemon MultipleException AnnotationConfiguration.scanForAnnotations

Tags: java, cargo, jetty-9

Jetty Version: jetty-distribution-9.2.2.v20140723

JDK: 1.7.0_65-b17

I am using the [Cargo Daemon](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Cargo+Daemon) with the cargo-jetty-7-and-onwards-deployer

I have updated the asm jars to 5.0.3 as suggested by other answers. But I am still receiving the below exception every other time.

My questions are has anyone experienced the same problem and have found the solution and how to I get more information from jetty (the cause(s)) of the Multiple Exception.

```
[Scanner-0] WARN  o.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext - Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1b6e5ef3
org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiException: Multiple exceptions
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.scanForAnnotations(AnnotationConfiguration.java:529) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:440) ~[jetty-annotations-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:471) ~[jetty-webapp-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1329) ~[jetty-webapp-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741) ~[jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:497) ~[jetty-webapp-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [jetty-util-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41) [jetty-deploy-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186) [jetty-deploy-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:498) [jetty-deploy-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:146) [jetty-deploy-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileChanged(ScanningAppProvider.java:198) [jetty-deploy-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileChanged(ScanningAppProvider.java:70) [jetty-deploy-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportChange(Scanner.java:663) [jetty-util-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:531) [jetty-util-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:391) [jetty-util-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$1.run(Scanner.java:329) [jetty-util-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505) [na:1.7.0_65]
```

It appears to occur when the webapps dependences change. and a redeploy is done.